How to create numbered text list in Android Jetpack Compose?
Similar to this question, given I have a List<String>, how would I create a composable function that creates a numbered/ordered and properly indented text list?
Here is what I am attempting to create:


Using this answer as a starting point I came up with this solution.
    @Composable
    fun makeNumberedList(items: List<String>): AnnotatedString {
        var bulletNumber = 1
        val textStyle = LocalTextStyle.current
        val textMeasurer = rememberTextMeasurer()
        val bulletStringWidth = remember(textStyle, textMeasurer) {
            textMeasurer.measure(text = "$bulletNumber.\t\t", style = textStyle).size.width
        }
        val restLine = with(LocalDensity.current) { bulletStringWidth.toSp() }
        val paragraphStyle = ParagraphStyle(textIndent = TextIndent(restLine = restLine))
    
        return buildAnnotatedString {
            items.forEach { text ->
                withStyle(style = paragraphStyle) {
                    append("${bulletNumber++}.\t\t")
                    append(text)
                }
            }
        }
    }

This is how It is used:
listOf("Short Text", 
       "Long Text - which is a really long text field so that it'll wrap the text.",
       "This is Medium Text!")
   .let {
        Text(text = makeNumberedList(it))
    }


fix for lineHeight and Double digit
fun OrderedList(items: List<String>): AnnotatedString {
    val textStyle = LocalTextStyle.current
    val textMeasurer = rememberTextMeasurer()
    val measureBulletString = remember(textStyle, textMeasurer) {
        textMeasurer.measure(text = "${items.size}.\t\t", style = textStyle).size
    }
    val restLine = with(LocalDensity.current) { measureBulletString.width.toSp() }
    val lineHeight = with(LocalDensity.current) { measureBulletString.height.toSp() }
    val paragraphStyle = ParagraphStyle(
        textIndent = TextIndent(restLine = restLine),
        lineHeight = lineHeight
    )

    return buildAnnotatedString {
        items.forEachIndexed { index, text ->
            withStyle(style = paragraphStyle) {
                append("${index+1}.\t\t")
                val longestNumberLength = items.size.toString().length
                if (longestNumberLength > 1) {
                    val extraTabs = longestNumberLength - (index+1).toString().length
                    for (i in 0 ..< extraTabs) {
                        append("\t")
                    }
                }
                append(text)
            }
        }
    }
}


Use monospace fo digist. The text may not be monospaced.
@Composable
fun orderedTextList(
    items: List<String>,
    style: TextStyle = LocalTextStyle.current,
    lineBreak: LineBreak = LineBreak.Paragraph
): AnnotatedString {
    val textMeasurer = rememberTextMeasurer()
    val monospaceStyle = style.copy(
        fontFamily = FontFamily.Monospace
    )

    val markerLen = items.size.toString().length
    val monospaceSize = textMeasurer.measure(text = " ", style = monospaceStyle).size
    val spaceSize =  textMeasurer.measure(text = " ", style = style).size
    val dotSize = textMeasurer.measure(text = ".", style = style).size

    return buildAnnotatedString {
        items.forEachIndexed { index, text ->
            val count = (index+1).toString().length
            val tailLen = markerLen - count
            withStyle(
                style = ParagraphStyle(
                    textIndent = TextIndent( restLine = with(LocalDensity.current) {
                        (monospaceSize.width *markerLen + dotSize.width + spaceSize.width).toSp()
                    }),
                    lineHeight = with(LocalDensity.current) { monospaceSize.height.toSp() },
                    lineBreak = lineBreak
                )
            ){
                withStyle(monospaceStyle.toSpanStyle()){
                    append("${index+1}")
                }
                append(".")
                if(tailLen > 0){
                    withStyle(monospaceStyle.toSpanStyle()){
                        append("".padEnd(tailLen))
                    }
                }
                append(" ")
                append(text)
            }
        }
    }
}


